# Need a counter example

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, almost-everywhere

If  $f =
f^+-f^-$ and $g =
g^+-g^-$ in which we have: $f^-=g^-$ and $g^+ = f^+$ almost everywhere.
Does it imply that $f=g$ almost everywhere?
I know the answer is no. but I can't find any counter example.

Comment: From where do you take the answer to be 'no' ?

Comment: @Evargalo I guessed! because I couldn't prove it, so I'm looking for a counter example.

Comment: I don't know offhand whether the answer is yes or no, but I would suspect that it is yes, and would be tempted to work very hard to prove it. What would happen if $f\neq g$ on a set of positive measure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is yes.

Let $A^-=\{f^-\neq g^-\}$ and $A^+=\{f^+\neq g^+\}$

Then $\mu(A^-)=\mu(A^+)=0$

By finite union, $\mu(A^- \cup A^+)=0$

And obviously $\{f\neq g\}\subset (A^- \cup A^+)$, so $f=g$ almost everywhere.

Comment: Yes, this is quite the approach I was thinking about. +1. However, gentle hints rather than outright complete answers are far more instructive as they let OP discover the proof himself.

Comment: @Evargalo thanks a lot, it was easier than what i thought I made myself so confused.